# Traduire « loose cannon » : franc-tireur, électron libre, ou mieux que ça ?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, expressions

Je recherche une manière de rendre le sens de l'expression anglaise *loose cannon*, dans son sens figuré (voir par exemple [ici](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loose_cannon), le sens n° 2).

Les deux expressions françaises que j'ai proposées dans mon titre ne sont peut-être pas les seules envisageables, ce sont mes pistes de départ. Cependant, elles me semblent insatisfaisantes car elles ne comportent pas l'idée péjorative de manque de fiabilité. Elles mettent surtout en avant l'indépendance ou autonomie, et sont souvent présentées ou assumées comme (au moins potentiellement) des qualités.

Auriez-vous une meilleure idée pour décrire un élément d'un groupe dont l'individualisme et la fierté mettent le groupe en péril ?

---

**English reader version :**

**How to Translate « loose cannon » into french? *franc-tireur*, *électron libre*, or something better ?**

I'm searching for a french expression to translate the english *loose cannon*, in its figurative sense (see [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loose_cannon), definition #2)

The two french expressions I've put in the title are only my starting point propositions, but there are certainly more. I find them kind of unsatisfactory, because both can, depending on the context, convey a positive meaning and they lack the *"perilous for its own group"* part.

Do you have a better french alternative for *someone whose individualism and pride are endangering its own group (of partners, coworkers, ...)* ?

Comment: You are correct that "loose cannon" in English has NONE of the positive connotations that the two French options you mention in your question MIGHT have (or MIGHT NOT have ...I'm not getting in to that debate here). As far as I know, "loose cannon," as you suggest, is ALWAYS negative, except, of course, at their bi-monthly "Loose Cannon Meet-ups"!  (Nothing to do with your question but perhaps interesting enough to note: in English the separate term "Lone Wolf", in the right context would, I think, accurately capture the POTENTIALLY positive notions of the two French options mentioned.)

Comment: Le plus proche en gardant l'image est « bombe à retardement » (plutôt que le bombe ambulante de @PapaPoule) à ceci près que *loose canon* s'emploie pour des personnes, et que « bombe à retardement  » s'emploie plutôt pour des choses/événements.

Comment: d'une manière générale et sous nos latitudes, je dirais que franc-tireur comme "électron libre" ont justement une connotation légèrement péjorative. On n'aime généralement pas "ce qui dépasse" ou ceux qui font preuve de trop de personnalité/originalité dans un groupe...

Comment: The notion of group/partners/coworkers is tough to find in an otherwise suitable French word (which is exactly what makes this an extremely interesting question, IMO). If all else fails, as a last resort maybe you could just use the appropriate possessive pronoun with whatever word/phrase that otherwise works best, e.g., "notre [loose cannon]"; "leur [loose cannon]"; etc to make the connection to a particular group (or by simply adding "du groupe" after the word/phrase that otherwise fits: "[the loose cannon] du groupe.") Regardless, I'll keep thinking about it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tout comme "Unpredictable" qui est utilisé dans le lien, je le traduirai simplement **"Imprévisible"**.

Si une expression est vraiment nécessaire, je pense que [Tête brûlée](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%AAte_br%C3%BBl%C3%A9e) conviendrait également.

Comment: +1 pour *tête brûlée*. Par contre *imprévisible* ne me paraît pas très à propos.

Comment: (+1) Même si on est à mi chemin entre *loose cannon* et *hothead*, j'aime aussi ton idée de *tête brûlée*. On s'approche, il me semble.

Comment: En plus de tête brûlée, j'aurais proposé *élément incontrôlable*

Answer (score 10):

On se méfie d'un électron libre. Il n y a aucune connotation positive mais bien une notion d'inquiétude à l'idée de ce qu'il pourrait faire. Cela me semble être l'expression la plus appropriée pour traduire loose cannon.

Comment: Oui, il m'avait semblé que cette connotation existait pour *électron libre*, mais beaucoup plus atténuée que pour *loose cannon* qui n'a jamais (sauf, j'imagine, cas exceptionnels) un sens positif. Cela dit, c'est vrai que je trouve *électron libre* plus juste que *franc-tireur* à cet égard.

Comment: @RomainVALERI C'est que c'est agir "indépendamment de toute institution." J'imagine que selon que l'institution visée est le "mariage" ou "société", il y a différence?

Comment: Un electron libre possède la faculté de s'attacher a n'importe quel atome ... la métaphore reflète donc bien l’indépendance mais c'est sans connotation négative car cela ne présage aucunement des conséquences.

Comment: J'ai toujours utilisé cette expression lorsque je ressentais une certaine inquiétude quant à la suite des événements. We will have to agree to disagree. :)

Comment: @Iside Il me semble au final que le terme *électron libre* contient à la fois des connotations positives et négatives (même si je pense que c'est plus souvent légèrement négatif, pour nuancer ton propos), qui dépendront souvent du contexte d'énonciation. Mais trouver des emplois positifs de *loose cannon* me semble nettement plus ardu.

Answer (score 5):

Que pensez vous de "chien fou" ou de "danger public" ?

D'autres expressions me sont passées par la tête même si elles ne correspondent pas ou peu :

Mouton noir

Cheval de Troie

Untel est un poison

Le loup dans la bergerie

Comment: Je trouve *danger public* assez différent dans la mesure où ce n'est pas le nom d'un rôle au sein d'un groupe mais de la société toute entière. C'est *chien fou* qui me plait nettement plus. Merci de la contribution (+1).

Answer (score 3):

You didn’t ask for neologisms so this should probably be a comment, but maybe a combination of « franc-tireur » and « la gâchette facile » would erase some of the positive connotations of « franc-tireur » by itself:

> un franc-tireur à (or “avec”) la gâchette facile.

“[Une bombe ambulante](https://glosbe.com/en/fr/loose%20cannon)” was also used for “loose cannon” at the same site where I ran across different translations of "loose cannon," including « franc-tireur » by itself and « [avoir] la gâchette facile » by itself.

Comment: Je ne suis pas entièrement convaincu par cette *bombe ambulante*, mais en revanche je note que c'est une allitération presque aussi chouette que *Papa Poule* :-)

Answer (score 3):

Il y a aussi "grenade dégoupillée" mais pour moi, "tête brûlée" est probablement le plus proche ...